# How can i retrieve only specific fields from xml in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

How can I retrieve only 'Are' from xml in python

```
< parameter name="Job Name" source="constant" updatable="True"> HELLO </ parameter>
< parameter name="GUIName" source="constant" updatable="True"> How </ parameter>
< parameter name="Task Name" source="constant" updatable="True"> Are </ parameter>
< parameter name="No Name" source="constant" updatable="True"> You </ parameter>
```

This is giving all elements

```
items=mydoc.getElementsByTagName('parameter name')
for i in items:
    OP=i.attributes['name'].value
```

Comment: Please explain what do you try to do - it is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
items=mydoc.getElementsByTagName('parameter name') 
for i in items:
    if ( OP:=i.attributes['name'].value == 'Are'):
    # do your stuff ('Are' is assigned to OP)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the below - the code below  fetch the attributes of the element that has text == Are

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<r><parameter name="Job Name" source="constant" updatable="True"> HELLO </parameter> 
         <parameter name="GUIName" source="constant" updatable="True"> How </parameter> 
         <parameter name="Task Name" source="constant" updatable="True"> Are </parameter>
         <parameter name="No Name" source="constant" updatable="True"> You </parameter></r>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
are_list = [p for p in root.findall('.//parameter') if p.text.strip() == 'Are']
for are in are_list:
    print(are.attrib)
```

output

```
{'name': 'Task Name', 'source': 'constant', 'updatable': 'True'}
```